# concourse git resource error: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused "EOF"

Tags: docker-compose, concourse

when trying to pull a git resource we are getting an error

```sh
runc run: exit status 1: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:303: getting the final child's pid from pipe caused \"EOF\""
```

we are using oracle linux - release 7.6. Docker version 18.03.1-ce.

we have followed the instructions on https://github.com/concourse/concourse-docker. we have tried with older versions of concourse (4.2.0 & 4.2.3). we can see the workers are up using fly.

we found this: https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/4021 on github which had a similar issue but couldn't find the relating story on stack overflow which the answerer had mentioned.

our docker compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: concourse
      POSTGRES_USER: concourse_user
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: concourse_pass

  web:
    image: concourse/concourse
    command: web
    links: [db]
    depends_on: [db]
    ports: ["61111:8080"]
    volumes: ["<path to repo folder>/keys/web:/concourse-keys"]
    environment:
      CONCOURSE_EXTERNAL_URL: <our url>
      CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_HOST: db
      CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_USER: concourse_user
      CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_PASSWORD: concourse_pass
      CONCOURSE_POSTGRES_DATABASE: concourse
      CONCOURSE_ADD_LOCAL_USER: test:test
      CONCOURSE_MAIN_TEAM_LOCAL_USER: test


  worker:
    image: concourse/concourse
    command: worker
    privileged: true
    depends_on: [web]
    volumes: ["<path to repo folder>/keys/worker:/concourse-keys"]
    links: [web]
    stop_signal: SIGUSR2
    environment:
      CONCOURSE_TSA_HOST: web:2222
```

we expected the resource to pull as the connectivity to the repo is in place and verified.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about your second issue with volumes, but I solved the original problem by setting user.max_user_namespaces parameter to 15000:

`sysctl -w user.max_user_namespaces=15000`

The solution was found here: https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/7962

Answer (score 0):

This issue was fixed by updating the kernal from 3.1.x to 4.1.x. we have a new issue:  `failed to create volume` on all our pipelines. i will update if i find a solution to this too